# Make Jenkins instance available over internet: away from localhost

Tags: jenkins, ip, webserver, localhost

My Jenkins instance is working currently on locahlhost on port 8080. 
Its running on Ubuntu. Now I would like to make the instance available through its public IP. Can you please explain how I can configure it? I would like to create a user also who can access the jenkins instance.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a question on how to setup a webserver? Not something related to jenkins really?

Comment: Well, part of it yes I agree, but where on Jenkins do I need to make the changes?

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins

You have an example their on how to configure it in Ubuntu.